# generating text texture in webgl: Alpha is opaque

Tags: canvas, text, textures, webgl, dynamically-generated

I'm generating a texture from a canvas that contains text, the problem is that the transparent part of the text is completely ignored when I render the texture.

[image: comparision]

When I render the texture it looks like the top text, when it should look like the bottom text.

This is how I generate the texture:

```
canvas.width = textRendBuffC.measureText(text).width*2;
canvas.height = parseInt(fontStyle, 10)*1.5;
c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
c.font = fontStyle;
c.fillStyle = colorStyle;
c.fillText(text, 0, parseInt(fontStyle, 10));


var canvasTexture = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, canvasTexture);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL,true);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
```

And this is how I draw the texture:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.vertBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentShader.sh.vertexAttribLocation, spritePlan.vertBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.texCoordBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentShader.sh.textureCoordAttribute, spritePlan.texCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.colorBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentShader.sh.colorAttribLocation, spritePlan.colorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.uniform1i(currentShader.sh.sampler2DUniform, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.indexBuffer);
setMatrixUniforms();

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, spritePlan.indexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

And this is the code the fragment shader goes through:

```
vec4 tex = texture2D(sampler2DUniform, vTextureCoord);
gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.rgb, tex.a);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your solution in answer and then accept it, remove it from the question see [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL` paramter to `true` ([`pixelStorei`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302429(v=vs.85).aspx)). This will cause the the color channels to be multiplied by the alpha channel, The initial value is `false`:

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
```

See [WebGL Fundamentals - textures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/pixelStorei):

> This tells WebGL to supply premultiplied alpha values to `gl.texImage2D` and `gl.texSubImage2D`. If the data passed to `gl.texImage2D` is already premultiplied as it is for Canvas 2D data then WebGL can just pass it through.

See Khronos specification [Premultiplied Alpha, Canvas APIs and texImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/):

> When passing a WebGL-rendered Canvas to the texImage2D API, then depending on the setting of the premultipliedAlpha context creation parameter of the passed canvas and the `UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL` pixel store parameter of the destination WebGL context, the pixel data may need to be changed to or from premultiplied form.

Further, you set up the texture paramter `TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` with `NEAREST`:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
```

See the Khronos OpenGL reference for [Sampler Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object):

> The magnification filter is controlled by the `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` texture parameter. This value can be `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST`. If `GL_NEAREST` is used, then the implementation will select the texel nearest the texture coordinate; this is commonly called "point sampling". If `GL_LINEAR` is used, the implementation will perform a weighted linear blend between the nearest adjacent samples.

This means, if you use `NEAREST`, then the the nearest texel is read from the texture, according to the texture coordinates. This causes a hard and angular appearance.
If you set the texture parameter `TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `LINEAR`, the texels will be interpolated and the weighted average of the 4 pixels surrounding the given coordinate is calculated.  The result is a smoother appearance:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
```

See also:

- [WebGL 3D - Textures](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)
- [Textures objects and parameters](https://open.gl/textures)

Comment: I found a solution:  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);

This tells WebGL to supply premultiplied alpha values to gl.texImage2D and gl.texSubImage2D. If the data passed to gl.texImage2D is already premultiplied as it is for Canvas 2D data then WebGL can just pass it through.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to use alpha as transparency in WebGL you have to enable blending with the correct blend equation. The typical one is:

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I see nothing related to blending in your code, did you set it elsewhere, what blend equation do you use ?

Comment: Totally in accord with you, BUT... i don't have enough reputation to post comments, so, how am I supposed to do ? :)